# Nested conditionals and unspecified return value in scheme

Tags: scheme, sicp

I'm trying to write a function that adds the two highest values out of three parameters.

`(define (sumhighest a b c) (cond

                            ((and (>= a b) (>= a c))    (if (>= b c) (+ a b) (+ a c)))
                            ((and (>= b a) (>= b c))    (if (>= a c) (+ a b) (+ b c)))
                            ((and (>= c a) (>= c b))    (if (>= a b) (+ a c) (+ b c))))
)`

Whenever I use the function I get the message "unspecified return value". I don't know what isn't working here. I.e:

```
(sumhighest 1 2 3)
```

EDIT: some people have pointed out that this code is working for them. I am using the mit-scheme implementation of the interpreter. It's under the package called mit-scheme on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: The code above works for me, it returns 5.  (I am using Racket and it works with both #lang racket and #lang sicp).  You might want to double check that you are running the code/definition that you think you are, or edit your question to provide more information about which implementation of Scheme you are using.

Comment: Done, thanks! mit-scheme

Comment: I'm using mit-scheme 10.1.10 and it works for me. You should always add a `else` in `cond` so if you are sure that if the two first didn't match that you can repleace you predicate with `else` og add ` else` as an additional term. Then your code is immune against badly chosen default values. The spec leaves it to th eimplementation so they could have returned `5` or `"BaNaNa"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be implementation-dependent, but as mentioned in the comments, it's working for some of us. Without having more context, I'd suggest you replace the last condition `(and (>= c a) (>= c b))` with just an `else`. Or switch to a different interpreter :)

Comment: I might have to switch to racket. I know this can be done in a multitude of ways, and this just was an effort to explore the language. I was dumbfounded about this error, and if this sort of stuff doesn't work, most problems will require unnecessary workarounds. Thanks for the answer.